# Undefined reference to InterlockedCompareExchange with boost.thread on mingw64 (but not on mingw32)

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, boost-thread, mingw-w64

I'm on a fedora 19 x86_64 computer, with mingw64 and all the relevant packages installed. I was working on a personal c++ project, and i decided to make it thread-safe, and so I decided to give Boost.thread synchronization objects a try. As soon as I did, I started to get linker errors related to InterlockedCompareExchange. The following test program illustrates my point:

```
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::shared_mutex mtx;
    boost::unique_lock<decltype(mtx)> lck{mtx};
}
```

Here's the command line (I put -lboost_thread-mt because there's no non-multithreaded version, which makes sense):

> $ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
>   -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system
>
> /tmp/cc4Wh6PO.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost12shared_mutex28interlocked_compare_exchangeINS0_10state_dataEEET_PS3_S3_S3_[_ZN5boost12shared_mutex28interlocked_compare_exchangeINS0_10state_dataEEET_PS3_S3_S3_]+0x2f):
>   undefined reference to `InterlockedCompareExchange' collect2: error:
>   ld returned 1 exit status

But with mingw32 it compiles like a charm:

> $ i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
>   -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system

My question is: am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in mingw64? Does it compile with the windows version of mingw?

Edit: actually it did, so it must be a bug in the fedora mingw64 package

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report.

Comment: This was fixed recently. Try updating your toolchain from the Fedora repos. If you experience this again, please submit a bug report to the Fedora tracker instead of using Stackoverflow as a fix-all.

Comment: I've given up on using boost::thread via MINGW64/GCC 4.7.1 (must build -m32 due to Irrlicht not being able to build 64-bit) due to this problem CreateThread and windows-only (sucks) it is I guess... :(  some defines indicating 64-bit MINGW still are true when -m32 and trips up the workaround macros to fix the _Interlocked and friends from failing.  I even tried creating a stub in one of my .cpp files for the failing _Itnerlocked* functions and still couldn't get it past the linker.

Comment: there are cases where this has not been fixed (eg: -m32 when using minGW/GCC 4.7.1) so someone in the know to create a workaround would be a useful answer here.

Comment: The InterlockedCompareExchange undefined errors are fixed in boost version 1.55.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact I still keep getting the same results, so I will definitely report it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Based on this page http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Building%20Boost, you can add define=BOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H to avoid that linking error. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue of undefined reference to Interlocked* functions.
As far as I know, mingw64 rev2 from MinGWBuilds project (on sf) is working, while rev3 is not working. So I belive it is something changed in MinGW64.